# How to process element list by using rstrip and lower()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I use this code:

```
test_list = ['A','a','word','Word','If,','As:']

for a in test_list:
    str(a)
    a.rstrip('.' or '?' or '!' or '"' or ":" or ',' or ';')
    a.lower()
    print(a)
print(test_list)
```

I got result like this:

```
A
a
word
Word
If,
As:
['A', 'a', 'word', 'Word', 'If,', 'As:']
```

An I was looking for something like:

```
a
a
word
word
if
as
['a','a','word','word','if','as']
```

I want to convert all elements in a list and strip all the marks off, so only if the word for me to process.

Comment: maybe read the doc of the function you are using? `lower` and `rstrip` do not work inplace but return a value, and `rstrip('.' or '?' or '!' or '"' or ":" or ',' or ';')` is equivalent to `rstrip('.')` because `.` is interpreted as `True`

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do everything you requested by using a generator expression:

```
# Test List
test_list = ['A', 'a', 'word', 'Word', 'If,', 'As:']

# Remove certain characters and convert characters to lower case in test list
test_list = [str(a).strip('.?!":,;').lower() for a in test_list]

# Print test list
print(test_list)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'a', 'word', 'word', 'if', 'as']
```